# How can I find the current position of the stack without a stack pointer?

Tags: c, stack

I was asked in an interview how will you find stack position without using stack pointer you were given with upper bound of stack and depth of stack. I couldn't give the answer. Later I googled the same, but couldn't get one. Can anybody please help me finding the answer.

Comment: What do they mean with “upper bound”? Could it be that they wanted you to trace down the return addresses and were actually interested in the *bottom* of the stack?

Comment: @5gon12eder upperbound means the max elements the stack can hold

Comment: @LiorA I thought so too but then this information doesn't seem very helpful in order to solve the problem.

Comment: @harikrishnan v nair   , depth can be defined in various ways if depth defined as "the amount of elements being used" as stack with ubound= 6 depth=4 , by that definition it's a trivial answer=it's depth [(a) (b) (c) (d) () () ] <-head direction , but if you define it as the amount of elements that you can insert it's upperbound - depth. to my knowledge the first definition is the more common (never seen "official" definition in cormen)

Answer (score 2):

Just create a variable on the stack (i.e. with 'automatic storage') and take its address.

```
void f() {
    int x;
    printf("Current stack position: %p\n", &x);
}
```

Comment: it's one answer but I feel it's not what they were directing him to you haven't used the data that was given: stack upperbound and it's depth(one must define well stack depth)

Answer (score 0):

I think is a way to listen the several solution you would give. 
So let us start with a fully pointer stack of int:

```
struct stack{
  int *pos;
  int *start;
  int *end;
}
struct stack new_stack(size_t size)
{
   struct stack * res=malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
   res->start=malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
   res->pos=res->start;
   res->end=res->start+size-1;
}
```

than the position is gave by:

```
  return res->pos-res->start;
```

But I think it was vorbidden;
So let us define a index (this is not pointer):

```
  struct stack{
  int ix;
  int *array;
  int n;
}
struct stack *new_stack(size_t size)
{
   struct stack * res=malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
   res->array=malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
   res->ix=0;
   res->n=size;
   return res;
}

 //you return 
 return res->ix;
```

Other solution is a placeholder with a not valid value. But is dumb since each time you should score the whole array. (it is like the null terminating strings)
Or otherwise if these two answer where not satisfing the right answer were "it is not possible" 
The stack upperbound is possible only if the array is declared static array[100].
than you get upperbound as sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array). But if you are going to write the code for a stack you write it dinamic